# logical operators as conditionals in c

Tags: c

I'd like to do the following:

```
r = recv(socket, buffer, bufsize, 0) && return r;
```

which doesn't work because `return -r;` isn't an expression. However,

```
r = recv(socket, buffer, bufsize, 0) && printf("r=%d\n", r);
```

seems to work. Now, there's not a whole lot to gain from this apart from syntactical brevity but I'm still curious if there's a way to accomplish the functionality of `&& return r;` that actually compiles?

EDIT: If it wasn't clear, the expression after the `&&` should be executed if and only if the first one is non-zero.

Comment: is there a pressing need to write the code like that rather than in a more clearer & verbose way?

Comment: I do not know what was your previous language of choice, however C does not work that way. Please learn about the `if` statement in C. Also, please keep in mind that `recv()` could also return `-1`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Nope! But it's kind of bash-idiomatic (at least it seems that way) so I figured the intent would be pretty clear.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I'm not asking if this is a good idea or not. I'm asking if it's doable.

Comment: @user7893856 I am not telling if this is a good idea or not. Compiler already told you it's not. I am giving you direction to use a proper C construct to achieve required result.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (...) return ...;`?

Comment: The part after `&&` is only executed if the first part results in `TRUE`. Nevertheless `r` is not assigned any value before the whole monster of an expression is evaluated and is not available for printing at this time.

Comment: What is `-` in `return -r;` supposed to indicate? Negation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a **bad** idea but just since you want it, here you go

```
r = recv(socket, buffer, bufsize, 0) && (({return r;}),0);
```

This will work as you want.

I can explain what is happening if you need.
I repeat it is bad idea.

Apart from being a bad idea this solution uses a gcc extension named - [Statement-expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). So this answer is not portable across compilers.

Comment: Ah, the mighty comma-operator, nice!! (Not upvoting, as you yourself mentioned, it's bad code). :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think so, but then, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - [I found the answer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (GCC extension). Still nice though.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think the doubt would be regarding `({statement})`. I am checking it that is standard

Comment: BTW, following the GCC documentation, you could remove some parentheses in the last expression `({return r; 0;})`. But it's a matter of taste, I think.

Comment: @StoryTeller so, yes it is a gcc extension. Even gcc complains *warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions* with -pedantic. Not standard then.

Comment: Even after writing "bad" twice (once with bold) the author accepted this answer. I will just throw a few more in - bad, bad, bad, bad, bad, bad, bad. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya it's an interesting feature, just add it's not (standard) C and anyone reading this later will know without reading the comments :)

Comment: I understand what's going on so there's no problem there. If anything, I'd like to know if this is a bad idea for reasons other than clarity, readability or dogma.

Comment: This will not compile on a standard C compiler. Bad idea. The OP did not mention GCC anywhere so this does not answer the question.

Comment: expression-statement is specific to gcc, not to the C language in general.

Comment: One word: ugly. Upvoted, however, for pointing out that it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

> the expression after the && should be executed if and only if the first one is non-zero.

And here is your problem: *expressions* aren't *executed*, they are *evaluated*. Statements are executed.

Expressions can have *side effects* happening during evaluation, but they *always* evaluate to some value. As you have already learned, `return` is a *statement* and not an *expression*.

So, in short, no, there's no way for what you want to do.

Comment: I mean... I don't understand the upvotes since there is clearly a way to do this by using GCC extensions. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @user7893856 GCC extensions are **not C**, so what's wrong here is your comment.

Comment: @user7893856 I upvoted this answer for pointing out (and highlighting) elementary language concepts that many people don't understand.

Comment: You probably mean that GCC extensions are not ISO C. So you answer is still objectively wrong - and even if it hadn't been TECHNICALLY wrong, it would have been unnecessarily inexhaustive.

Comment: @user7893856 please read the tag description for [tag:c]: "*Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 9899 that ISO currently lists as active.*". Apart from that, without explicitly mentioning extensions, anyone talking about C refers to the standardized language.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` is syntactically an `expression` (function call) while `return __` is a `jump-statement`.

The operator `&&` requires 2 operands of type `expression`, this is why it rejects your code.

Look at `Appendix A` in the `ISO 9899`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

```
r = recv(socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);
if (r != 0)
{
  return r;
}
```

If you are searching for something more complicated than that, you are doing it wrong. Good programmers strive for simplicity, bad programmers strive for obfuscation.